# Explicit lifetimes change the function signature and make the function incompatible for the required type signature

Tags: rust

```
#![feature(rustc_private)]
#![feature(box_syntax)]
extern crate rustc;
extern crate rustc_driver;

use rustc::hir::intravisit as hir_visit;
use rustc::hir;
use rustc_driver::driver::{CompileController, CompileState};

pub struct SomeVisitor<'a, 'tcx: 'a> {
    pub map: &'a hir::map::Map<'tcx>,
}

impl<'v, 'tcx: 'v> rustc::hir::intravisit::Visitor<'tcx> for SomeVisitor<'v, 'tcx> {
    fn nested_visit_map<'this>(&'this mut self) -> hir_visit::NestedVisitorMap<'this, 'tcx> {
        hir_visit::NestedVisitorMap::All(self.map)
    }
}

fn hir(s: &mut CompileState) {
    let krate = s.hir_crate.unwrap();
    let map = s.hir_map.unwrap();
    let mut visitor = SomeVisitor { map };
    hir_visit::walk_crate(&mut visitor, krate);
}

fn main() {
    {
        let mut controller = CompileController::basic();
        controller.after_hir_lowering.callback = box hir;
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0b20f69f7ef2e5aeb8bc7f242176eca6&version=nightly)

I understand why I am getting the lifetime error and it is very easy to solve it by adding explicit lifetimes for the function `hir`.

```
pub fn walk_crate<'v, V: hir_visit::Visitor<'v>>(visitor: &mut V, krate: &'v Crate) {}
```

Because of this definition the lifetime for the reference needs to live for `'tcx`.

```
fn hir<'v, 'tcx>(s: &'tcx mut CompileState<'v, 'tcx>) {
    let krate = s.hir_crate.unwrap();
    let map = s.hir_map.unwrap();
    let mut visitor = SomeVisitor { map };
    hir_visit::walk_crate(&mut visitor, krate);
}
```

But then the function `hir` becomes incompatible for the callback. [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ba2517602ba3d449ca63cb067750eda0&version=nightly)

I assume that I may need to use [HRTB](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html) here?

Update:

My current workaround is to use transmute. ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8861d2e6b36ea4e0582c83b8275b4905&version=nightly)). Surely there must be a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hir_visit::walk_crate(&mut visitor, visitor.map.krate());
```

The solution was to realize that map also contains a krate as a reference, but with the correct lifetime. This means that I don't have to introduce explicit lifetimes.

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=57dc44b0d8e8f7461df8ba812a05e335&version=nightly)